# Validar en Java que un json entrante concuerde con el modelo de Clase

Tags: java, json, validación

Necesito validar un json que llega desde el request body, algunos campos son requeridos pero si el json no los tiene, estos son devueltos como nulos:

```
@Document(collection = "menus")
public class Module {

    /** The module name as unique identifier. */
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String name;

    /** The internationalization key. */
    private String i18n;

    /** The Angular state. */
    private String state;

    ...
}
```

Si el json que llega con una estructura sin el campo name, por ejemplo:

```
{
    "i18n": "INVOICES",
    "state": "/invoices"
}
```

el Module es valido y persistido como:

```
{
    "name": null,
    "i18n": "INVOICES",
    "state": "/invoices"
}
```

Para validar este campo en el json que llega, cree un Validator como éste:

```
public class MenuValidator implements Validator {

    /** The menu service. */
    private MenuService service;

    public MenuValidator(MenuService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> objectClass) {
        return objectClass.equals(Module.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {

        try {
           String name = ((Module) object).getName());
           if(name==null){
               errors.rejectValue("name", "name.null","The module name is null");
           }
    ...
}
```

Sin embargo esto es muy engorroso, sobretodo si el modelo se hace más complejo porque sería necesario validar muchos campos. ¿Existe alguna opción para hacer estas validaciones de forma más automática?

Comment: la validación la vas a tener que hacer de una manera u otra, si no quieres implementar un validator, puedes pensar (y deberías hacerlo como añadido) validar a traves de los `setters` de `Module`, aunque el validador a mi, me parece mas elegante.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como verifico que el json este lleno?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258281/como-verifico-que-el-json-este-lleno)

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo usar la instropeccion, con ella puedes hacer dinamica tu validator ejemplo :

```
Class[] classes = new Class[]{Module.class}
for(Class obj : classes){
            Object instance = obj.newInstance();
            for(Field field : obj.getFields()){
                //Aca compararias cada uno de los atributos de la clase con los elementos del json;
```

//
                }
            }

Comment: -1 porque usar el api de reflexion es la forma mas facil de afectar el performance de tu programa