# Como verifico que el json este lleno?

Tags: java, json, spring

Como verifico que todos los campos están llenos?
Todo inicia con el controller que necesita un tipo de clase UserBd

```
@PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<UserBd> createUser(@RequestBody UserBd user) {
        log.info("CREATE");
        return new ResponseEntity<UserBd>(userServiceImpl.createUser(user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Este es la clase userBd

```
public class UserBd implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public UserBd(){

    }
    public UserBd(String name, long id, String password, String email) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UserBd(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Este es el json, **como verifico que todos los campos esten llenos?**

```
{
  "email": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "password": "string"
}
```

Comment: Hola, ¿a qué te refieres con eso? Tienes una Clase y un JSON. ¿Deseas verificar que el JSON tenga todas las claves y sus valores? Porque imagino que lo usarás para instanciar tu Clase. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras  quiero comprobar si llego todos los datos al backend

Comment: Simple, convierte al Objeto Java y comprueba si sus valores tienen contenido.

Comment: En cualquier caso si usa "@Valid" y las anotaciones de "@NotNull" está obligado a que vengan rellenas. Si solo quieres comprobar si vienen rellenas o no (pueden ser nulas o no) basta con que hagas un user.getXXXXX();, para cada uno de los campos que tienes en user en el mismo controller. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para verificar que todos los campos tienen valor puedes usar la API de validación de Java.

En caso de que esté trabajando con un proyecto Maven, has de añadir las siguientes dependencias al pom.xml del módulo correspondiente.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Donde javax.validation es la especificación de las validaciones e hibernate provee la implementación.

Una vez que actualices las dependencias del proyecto, puedes usar las anotaciones de validación en cada campo de tu clase Userdb.

En tu caso, para comprobar que no son nulos debes usar la anotación @NotNull. Además, para comprobar cadenas no vacías existe la anotación @NotEmpty:

```
public class UserBd implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String name;

@Column(name = "password")
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String email;

....
}
```

Finalmente, para ejecutar las validaciones al recibir la petición en el controlador, debes usar la anotación @Valid. En caso contrario, las validaciones no se ejecutarán.

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<UserBd> createUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserBd user) {
    log.info("CREATE");
    return new ResponseEntity<UserBd>(userServiceImpl.createUser(user) HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Nota**: Las dependencias de hibernate serán añadidas automáticamente si usas Spring Boot.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Aquí tienes un enlace donde se explica en detalle cada validación y cómo usarla:
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation